# What would it take for a spacecraft to travel to the sun's nadir and stop?

Tags: space, space-travel, spaceships, orbital-mechanics

In a science fiction future universe, spacecraft routinely travel from a distance "above" a star's north or south pole to rendezvous with planets orbiting in the star system's orbital plane. And vice versa.

As a writer, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the orbital dynamics involved. How hard would it be for a spacecraft to leave Earth's orbit, transit out of the orbital plane to a point "above" the star, and rendezvous with another craft that's stationary relative to that point? (I.e,. the rendezvous point is not orbital to the sun.)

If it helps the discussion, let's assume the distance to the point above the star is the same as the distance from the sun to Saturn.

I've been looking at the flight path of the [Ulysses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_(spacecraft)) spacecraft, but as it orbited the sun and didn't have to "stop" relative to a point above the star, I'm not sure it's a good model for what would have to happen.

If it helps, the setting assumes that the spacecraft rarely accelerates/decelerates greater than 1 *[g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth)* for long periods for the comfort of its crew. The technology is vaguely like ours, but it assumes that the amount of fuel required is not a limiting factor.

Comment: Why would they want to park there? They'll need to constantly fire their thrusters to keep from falling into the sun, and they're not on average any closer to (and are indeed usually further from) planets in the system than they would be by simply occupying a small orbit around the sun on the ecliptic plane.

Comment: That's kinda the question I'm asking myself, honestly. For now I'm trying to understand what would be required if that's what they need to do, for reasons, as opposed to what could be done differently. (Yes there are in universe reasons but it's not really worth delving into, in order to understand the requirements of this particular task.)

Comment: We need all but one of: initial and final mass (rocket plus fuel), rocket exhaust velocity, time of the flight, and whether the rocket flips and reverses its burn or burns all one direction.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie That's an interesting point, but not germane to the post. Why the rocket must stop is a story-based issue and is not necessary to obtain an answer to this question.

Comment: @Scottoooooo You're somewhat misusing the word "[nadir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadir)." Astronomically, the nadir is the *direction* from an arbitrary point above a surface to its gravitational center (said another way, it's the vector describing the force of gravity). In other words, you can travel along the sun's nadir, but the "nadir" isn't a place at which you can stop.

Comment: Also whether you're taking the long way and shedding some of your energy by slingshotting around other planets, or trying to get there with some urgency - although if it's the former it's a lot harder to answer.

Comment: That's very interesting, JBH! I absolutely did not know that. Thanks! Is there a word that would describe a point directly above or below a star, perpendicular to the orbital plane?

Comment: @gs I can answer most of those questions with a little work. But yes: as quick and direct as possible, relying on it's own engines, for a range of spacecraft sizes from, say 200 kilotons and up. Would it accelerate and flip and burn midway to slow down for, say Earth capture orbit? Or would it have to accelerate to catch up with the planet's orbital velocity, with only a small deltaV for capture?

Comment: This would need two components. The first would get you out of the gravity well, and the second would accelerate you to orbital velocity. You could dive into the star and use its gravity to slingshot you out of its well, but then you'd need a burn to catch up to orbital velocity. I suggest you play with Kerbal Space Program to figure out specific paths.

Comment: @Scottoooooo I'm neither an astronomer nor a celestial mechanic by trade, so they may have better insight. Part of the problem is that you're thinking of a stationary point in a circumstance where there really isn't one. Another part is that the sun isn't a solid object. You could say something like "one million kilometers above the corona at the north ecliptic pole." That would (almost) specify a single point relative to the sun (but not "in space" as the sun is moving...).

Comment: @NuclearHoagie : "Why would they want to?" Because it looks good in comic books. It' the best way to have the Sun, the planet, and the humongous spaceship in the frame at the same time, while all of them are "standing upright". It's also a good way to indicate the reader that the spaceship is recharging at the Sun, as it siphons energy "up". And "up" is relative to the format of the comic book page, so it would be awkward if it was "sideways". Similar to how spaceships always encounter each other in the same orientation, as if they were cruising on the ocean.

Comment: Sorry but there is no such thing as "the rendezvous point is not orbital to the sun.". You seem to be under the impression that the *orbital plane* of the planets is somehow special. The gravitational pull of the sun doesn't disappear at the solar system orbital axis.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing a point in space is distinct from an orbit. It is possible for something to exist in space at a location or in a trajectory that is not a keplerian orbit. Lagrange points are one such thing. The location of a [statite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statite) would be another.

Comment: @vsz You could simply orbit the star at 90 degrees to the planets, and you would at regular intervals  occupy that point for that sweet cover shot... not that you'd ever see the planets from that distance... but you know, artistic license is a thing that needs no basis in reality.

Comment: In space, you don't "stop".  If you want to go somewhere you can shut your engines off and just chill while maintaining distance from your destination, you either "orbit", "land" or "rendezvous".

Comment: Are you looking for [Lagrange points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_point)?

Answer (score 28):

A magic search term that might be of interest to you is [statite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statite). A statite balances the force of gravitational attraction to a body (such as a planet or star) with light pressure on a [solar sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail) (though other mechanisms could be used instead, such as a [magnetic sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_sail) or some other suitably science-fictional gadgetry). Such a spacecraft would not be orbiting and could remain "fixed" relative to that body, though it would probably have to trim its sails a bit from time to time if there were changes in light pressure or local gravity.

From recollection, the jump-ships in the Battletech universe assumed this position, using an energy-collecting solar sail to charge their FTL transport system.

The major issue you have is that transitioning from a solar equatorial-ish orbit (like the one that the Earth is in) to a solar-polar orbit is extremely expensive in terms of delta-V, and then once you reach your pole-sitting statite you need much more delta-V again to stop. If you have a super-efficient torch drive you might not have to worry about such a thing, of course.

> If it helps, the setting assumes that the spacecraft rarely accelerates/decelerates greater than 1 gee for long periods for the comfort of its crew. The technology is vaguely like ours

Accelerating at 1G for extended periods of time requires rockets of astonishing power and capability, and would be far beyond what humans are capable of for a considerable time. Be careful about going down the hard scifi route, for real world physics is tough to beat!

---

*addendum*

Now you've given a few more hints about what you're thinking about, I can add the following observations:

- Solar flux is negligible outside of the inner solar system. Even at Marslike distances from the sun it is too low, and by the time you get out to Saturnlike distances you'll barely notice it... a perfectly absorbing sail would experience ~50 *nanonewtons* of thrust per square metre. Solar collectors and solar sails are both largely pointless out here
- Gravity apparently obeys the same inverse-square laws as light, so at Saturnlike distances a Sunlike star only exerts about 6.5 microgees. You can acheive station-keeping thrusts against this using something an ion drive... the [Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)#Propulsion_system) space probe acheived a greater acceleration than this when fully loaded, and had enough fuel to run its rocket for years. Unlike a solar statite, your rocket-based things would need periodic refuelling.
- A [brachistochrone transit](https://projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/torchships.php#id--Brachistochrone_Equations) crossing 8 AU (eg. from an Earthlike distance to a Saturnlike distance from a star) at 1G continuous acceleration takes about 8 days and requires a [Delta-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-V) of ~7000 km/s. Even to fly a single AU at that acceleration is ~2400 km/s. That's a *lot*. Dawn had 11 km/s. You can't do this without serious nuclear rocketry, but if you *can* do it then you can consider the laws of orbital mechanics more as polite requests. For example, injecting yourself into a polar heliocentric orbit from an earthlike heliocentric orbit requires ~42 km/s delta-V... an outrageous amount for a modern-day or near-future spacecraft, but a rounding error for your monstrous things. They can just point where they want to do and blast and not worry too much. "Parking" by the non-orbital target and station-keeping to oppose the local gravity gradient would be trivial.

---

*addendum 2*

Because I thought it was an interesting discovery, even if it is obvious in retrospect, there's an equation you can derive from the force imparted by sunlight on a perfectly absorbing surface, and the force caused by the gravity of the sun an equation that tells you how large a sail would have to be in order to make a statite: $$C_{ad} = { L_\odot \over {4\pi c G M_\odot} }$$

The critical areal density of a solar sail, $C_{ad}$, in kilograms per square metre, is the ratio of the total mass of your statite (including the sail) to the surface area of the sail pointing directly at the Sun. $L_\odot$ is the [luminosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_luminosity) of the Sun, in watts, $M_\odot$ is the mass of the Sun, $c$ is the speed of light, and $G$ is the [gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant).

This ratio is independant of the distance of the sail from the Sun, because both light pressure and gravitational attraction obey the inverse square law, and so cancel each other out nicely. If the areal density of your statite exceeds this critical ratio, it will fall back towards the Sun and a firey demise. If it is *lower* than the critical ratio, it will be blown out into deep space, though possibly very slowly. In the latter case at least you can do station keeping by pointing your sail ever so slightly away from the sun to reduce sunlight pressure.

For the Sun, the critical ratio is ~0.765g/m<sup>2</sup>. Clearly, statites of any significant mass will need colossal sails of some exceedingly light, low density material. Using a solar-powered ion drive is probably a much more sensible way to hold yourself up, even if you do need periodic refuelling.

Comment: It is, in fact, a Battletech related writing question. Haha. Those are all things I was thinking, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something in the physics or orbital dynamics that made it more feasible somehow. Thank you for your thoughtful answer! One of the bottlenecks of my own research is my limited vocabulary for the questions I'm asking.

Comment: if you have a statite, couldn't the trimming of the sail alone let you move around pretty much anywhere in the solar system? (close/away from the star is tricky to balance, but any sideways on a sphere of equal distance should be fairly easy, no? (something like piloting a kite)

Comment: @Scottoooooo yeah, an awful lot of research is just knowing what magic words you should be asking. Happy to help!

Comment: @njzk2 you can, in fact, go more or less anywhere with the aid of a solar sail... you just need patience. Moving further away and staying there would be awkward, but you could fall in towards the star where radiation pressure is stronger and inject yourself into a suitably eccentric orbit that would carry you a long way out. Tricky to get out of that orbit again, though.

Comment: @njzk2 that's... Fantastically interesting!

Comment: FWIW, in the BattleTech universe, the sails the [JumpShips](https://www.sarna.net/wiki/JumpShip) use (lots of CamelCasing in BT) only serve to collect energy from the sun to charge the jump drive. Any role *of the sails* in keeping stationary is not addressed, and per canon, JumpShips have "a weak station-keeping drive" for that purpose.

Comment: @StephanKolassa it was certainly the case in earlier versions of the material that light pressure was relevant, though that seems to have been retconned in later releases. The details are somehat inconsistent, to be honest, but I hesitate to bring plausible physics to the table because I'm not sure the setting could withstand it ;-)

Comment: @StephanKolassa (having run some of the numbers that battletech uses, I can see that solar pressure at jump-point distance is negligible, but that also means that power-gathering capabilities of solar collectors at that distance are also negligible and given the apparent energy requirements of a KF drive it would make infinitely more sense to use a fusion reactor to charge it instead. and that's why you shouldn't bring physics to a game world with giant fighting robots)

Comment: Re trimming the solar sail to reduce radial direction thrust, you'd want multiple sails with mirrorred trim angles, so the angular direction thrusts sum to 0.

Comment: Dumb question, but why would you need much more Delta-V to stop than to get there?

Comment: @Blueriver poor phrasing on my part, more or less... it was mostly intended to mean "_you need even more on top of what you've just used up_". The equatorial-to-polar transition might need as much as ~42km/s (though a heliocentric polar injection from a low polar orbit about Earth could be cheaper) though braking to a relative halt would only take ~30km/s. I think about some rewording.

Comment: @StarfishPrime oh, that makes sense. I thought you meant you needed X to get there and Y>>X to stop, but you need X to get there and Y to stop and X is already a lot and X+Y is an even greater a lot. I was thinking you might be doing some "tricks" (slingshots, etc) to make exiting the orbital plane easier, which you can't do once outside the plane. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 10):

It's a hugely expensive thing to do, in terms of orbital mechanics.

The main issue is that simply being on (or in a bound orbit around) a planet that already orbits near the ecliptic means you already have a lot of energy from that planet's orbit. If you're going to another planet that orbits near the ecliptic (in the same direction), then most of that energy is "reusable" and thus a good thing.

For example, Earth orbits the Sun at about 30 km/s. Mars is a little less because it's further out, around 25 km/s. A simple Hohmann transfer from Earth orbit to Mars orbit only needs about 3 km/s change in velocity; this is an order of magnitude less than the orbital velocities that Earth and Mars are travelling at. So if you were "starting from scratch" with no useful orbital velocity in the ecliptic, it's **much** harder to reach Mars than it would be from near the orbit of just about any body orbiting the Sun, since you would need to provide enough energy to get up to the speed that Mars orbits at.

Travelling to or from a point really far from the ecliptic (like directly above or below the Sun) is also really difficult. If I'm orbiting near Earth and I want to get to the far side of the solar system, then I don't really need any energy; Earth's orbit will simply take me there if I wait 6 months. And we've seen that it takes relatively low amounts of *change* in velocity to travel interplanetary distances (eventually), by re-using the energy we already had form the starting orbit. But if I want to get to a point directly above the Sun and a similar distance as Earth's orbital distance, then "coasting" there would require me to be on an orbit with the same *speed* as Earth's orbit, but rotated 90°, so that I'm travelling "up" where Earth is travelling "sideways". Earth's orbital velocity is *never* pointing in a direction where I can re-use any of its energy for that, so I would have to provide all 30 km/s of it myself. Having done that, I would also still have the 30 km/s "sideways" velocity from Earth's orbit that is not useful, so I would have to provide enough energy myself to cancel out that velocity *on top* of the energy required for the "vertical" orbital velocity. (And if you want to "stop" at a position directly above the Sun, you then need to pay a similar magnitude energy cost **again** to zero out your orbital velocity as you pass overhead, not to mention whatever you're doing to staion-keep once you're there. I'm not saying that "thrust Earth-retrograde 30 km/s, then thrust perpendicular to the ecliptic 30 km/s, then coast to above the Sun and thrust retrograde 30 km/s" would *actually* be the most energy-efficient way to do this, but it gives you a ballpark idea of the *magnitudes* involved)

Nobody would plan these sorts of courses unless they have so much energy available that these astronomical energy costs are a minor issue to them, or unless there is some *very* compelling reason to go there. Given the existence of an ecliptic plane where most interesting things are orbiting near that plane (in the same direction), it's just **much** cheaper to travel in orbits on that plane.

Comment: The OP's stated spacecraft capabilities imply delta-V values of thousands of km/s or more. Injection into polar or retrograde heliocentric orbits would be trivial.

Comment: @StarfishPrime The capabilities of the OP's ships are up to them. I was just trying to convey an intuitive sense of just how much more costly this would be than more "normal" space journeys. The OP can decide how that affects their worldbuilding.

Answer (score 8):

### Pointless if you are using Newtonian physics.

Let's start with a minor frame challenge explaining why you should never under any circumstances see this done in any science-based setting.  Newtonian physics makes stopping over the sun a pointless waste of energy no matter how advanced your civilization becomes.  Even if you need to be able to see the whole solar system at once, you could orbit the sun and apply a much smaller Z-axis thrust to hold your ship "high" enough to be able to see planets on the far side of the sun.

Mercury's orbit is 47 million km from the sun, and the sun has a coronal radius of about 7-14 million km and a diameter of 0.7 million km.  So, if you orbit the sun at a the edge of its corona, and thrust your way up to about 0.8 million km above the planetary plane, you will be able to see Mercury from the far side of the sun allowing you to see all of the planets in the solar system without having to spend fuel on fully stopping and while using about 10-20 times less fuel to hold yourself above the planetary plane.

Even when you look at Starfish Prime's answer, orbital mechanics allow one to offset some of the needed efficiency for solar wind based lift.  So, instead of having to design an insanely light ship/sail, it makes more sense to design a sail big enough to capture the ideal amount of energy for cost of manufacture and maintenance, and then derive the remaining needed energy from orbital momentum.

Whether the thrust comes from rockets, the sun itself, or some theoretical antimatter drive etc. does not matter, because it will always be way cheaper to orbit.

[image]

### The only solution that makes since is if you use a reactionless drive

The only way to make a this a reasonable consideration is if you use a reactionless drive.  This is any theoretical engine that moves by non-newtonian principles like wormholes, improbability drives, parallel dimensions, etc.  Because these drives move without imparting any momentum, when you turn it off, you instantly return to a stationary position relative to your original reference frame.  If this is the case, coming to a dead stop over the sun could be a trick for using the star's gravity to slow you down so you can match reference frames after an interstellar jump.  If you need to stay there, you could just jump from one side of the star to the other, yo-yo-ing above the poles.

How hard is it to use a reactionless drive in this manner? ... no one knows.  The whole point of reactionless drives is that they don't obey the known laws of physics; so, until one is invented, there is no hard science answer to this question.  But the good thing as a writer when dealing with them is that no one can contradict the physics of a jump drive.  So, as long as you stay internally consistent, it's as hard or easy as you want it to be.

You could also perhaps have an Alcubierre meta-material drive.  A material that imparts a constant forward acceleration by warping spacetime. This would be a sort of "thruster" than once made, can never be turned off; so, by parking over the sun or a planet, at just the right distance, you could use the gravity well to cancel out your acceleration in which case, the answer is that it takes no energy at all... you'd just have to maneuver a bit inside the corrona at a range of 3.68 million kilometers to offset your 1G of acceleration.